# Bash (Posix) Regex does not match

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I'm trying to validate a password. 
The Password has to have at least a length of 7 and containing a numeric value and an alphabetic one.

My Regular expression works in multiple online testing tools like http://www.regextester.com/.

But for some reason wont work in my script.

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^((?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:alnum:]]).{7,})$ ]]; then
  printf "DEBUG: password match\n"
  return 0
else
  printf "DEBUG: password no match\n"
  return 1
fi
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: BASH regex doesn't support lookahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX regular expressions do not support Perl-style `(?=...)` look-ahead assertions. You can use simple pattern matching here.

```
if [[ $1 == *[[:digit:]]* && $1 == *[[:alpha:]]* && $1 =~ .{7} ]]; then
```

The first check ensures there is a digit, the second a letter. The last check verifies there is a 7-character substring somewhere in the value (which implies the total length is at least 7). You could replace that with `${#1} -ge 7` as well.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
password=$1
if [[ ${#password} -ge 7 && "$password" == *[A-Z]* && "$password" == *[a-z]* && "$password" == *[0-9]* ]]; then
   printf "DEBUG: password match\n"
else
   printf "DEBUG: password no match\n"
fi
```

Comment: This is slightly stricter; you require one uppercase letter *and* one lowercase letter, rather than just one letter.